# Loading .npy file that are too large for RAM

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, google-colaboratory, ram

I am trying to load a large .npy file (~800 MB) into Google Collab, but every time I try to do so, the Collab instance crashes due to RAM over usage.

```
     import numpy as np
     a=np.load('oddata.npy',allow_pickle=True)
```

I am using the basic Collab instance with 12 GB RAM.

I have tried using mmap, but it returns this error: ValueError: Array can't be memory-mapped: Python objects in dtype.

Is there anyway around the problem, like breaking the .npy file into chunks or converting it into another file format.

Best,

Araf

Comment: HDF5 support reading files by chunks. You can try to convert your file to HDF5 but you need at least to be able to open it on the machine making the conversion. You could do it on a machine with a swap memory quite large for example. Note however that HDF5 will not accept pure-Python objects and I think this is your main problem here. Why not use native types?

Comment: Really appreciate the quick response. The problem is that this is a prefabricated dataset, so I really didn't have the opportunity to create it any of the native types.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is more to your problem than insufficient memory. The 12 GB allocated in your Collab instance should be more than enough to read a 800MB file. To confirm, I ran a simple test on my Raspberry Pi (which only has 4GB RAM). It can create a 1GB .npy file and read it back in to a new array. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
nimg, n0, n1 = 1000, 512, 512
arr = np.arange(nimg*n0*n1).reshape(nimg,n0,n1)
print(arr.dtype, arr.shape)

np.save('SO_67671598.npy',arr)
arr2 = np.load('SO_67671598.npy')    
print(arr2.dtype, arr2.shape)
```

I get the same result with or without the `allow_pickle=True` parameter. Note that `allow_pickle=True` is not recommended (for security reasons). It is necessary when you are loading object arrays. I suggest you run this test in your Collab instance, and see what you get.

Comment: Sir, I tried the test you suggested, and was able to run it on my Collab instance without any issues. At this point I am suspecting that my data file is most likely corrupt. I am going to try to recreate the .npy file from the file loading script. Thank you very much for your time!